# Translation of a sentence in "Somniale Danielis"

Tags: sentence-translation

The book *"Somniale Danielis"* (print edition dated 13<sup>th</sup> century) is a list of common dreams along with the associated meaning by the author.
I came across this section but I can't figure out what it means:

[image: Agno id est preceptum facere signi. tedium]
`Agno [id est]? pr(a)eceptum facere signi(ficat) tedium`

**NOTES:**

- The `s` and `f` use the same exact stroke.
- Same with `v` and `u` (as expected).
- It's very difficult to distinguish between `t` and `r`.

What i think this means:

`Agnō praeceptum facere significat taedium.`

> Giving a command to a lamb means boredom.

But I'm not sure, given the `id est`.

**In other parts of the text I noticed:**

- Using a `π` like stroke to denote `et`.
- Unsettling use of macrons to shorten words (`bonū` => `bonum`).
- Using a `3` when shortening something again.

**Other example:**
[image: Aurum et arg(en)tum tractāre s(ignificat) expedītiōnē(s) de factīs tuīs.]
`Aurum [et] arg(en)tum tractāre s(ignificat) expedītiōnē(s) de factīs tuīs.`

Comment: This manuscript looks like it's actually unusually good about distinguishing [long s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s) (ſ) from f (and I don't see why you find it difficult to distinguish t from r). ⁊ is a [Tironian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tironian_notes) *et*, which is still used in Ireland today. What you call a macron in *bonū* for *bonum* is actually a tilde (even if it's written as a straight line), and is extremely common in manuscripts of almost all periods to indicate unwritten *n* or *m* (Spanish *ñ* actually reflects earlier *nn*).

Comment: And ꝫ after *e* stands for *m*, not *s*. Paleography is a big field and the conventions of Latin manuscripts are non-trivial. This one looks friendly, though.

Comment: You have transcribed the letters correctly. I agree with you that *id est* is odd. Do you have a link to the full text? More context always helps, to compare this line with others.

Comment: I have yet to find a line that uses `id est` that way https://collections.nlm.nih.gov/catalog/nlm:nlmuid-9412012-bk

Comment: It looks like there's a capital the manuscript owner neglected to have painted in and maybe the word should actually be *bagno*. It's not consistent with the start of the As but the line is definitely in with the Bs (the previous line definitely has *baculum*). Obviously *bagno* isn't Latin, and neither is *bannare* on the next line (*annare* is, but it doesn't seem to work).

Comment: annare means to swim, from anno https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/annare#Latin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Cairnarvon notes it is most probably not starting with A, but with B. As clearly suggested by the preceding entry Baculum which also matched the alphabetical order.

[Other versions](https://books.google.com/books?id=Viv5NQLXH1IC&pg=PP13&lpg=PP13&dq=%22barbam%20longam%20babere%22&source=bl&ots=L5ZcFt3x0n&sig=ACfU3U1eBInHLfnL0T_B-EkSCjPX0p750w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijq7nYudP9AhWK76QKHTsmCuQQ6AF6BAgHEAM#v=onepage&q=%22barbam%20longam%20babere%22&f=false) indeed have Baculum, and then *Bannum* (instead of *Agno*). There could be hardly any doubt the word is indeed *Bannum* as we find later also in the OP's Agno's version the line *"Bannum seu praeceptum audire..."*

[image]

From here the entire interpretation follows naturally. The author thankfully gives the reader the meaning of the word *bannum*. He says "Bannum id est praeceptum". Skimming the text we see this formula in a page later under the term "Bordonem" where the author writes is trabs: "Bordonem id est trabem videre significat deceptionem"

The following term *"Bannare"* probably means *to give commands/order.* Hence I'll translate the two entries thus:

> To perform a command (*Bannum*) means weariness.
> To give orders or to see (someone) performs command means anger.